# php Access violation

Tags: php, drupal, administration

I am trying to install Php on Vista (IIS 7). The installation and configuration seems to be fine. Pretty much followed everything mentioned in http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/09/19/How-to-install-PHP-on-IIS7-_2800_RC1_2900_.aspx

I can even bring up a test.php which is basically  and can also connect to mysql db through code. But when I try to bring up some other php page like drupal's index page or phpmyadmin  index page, it brings up a Php access violation message.

Any clue whats happening? Also is there some tracing/diagnositic tool for php to trace whats happenign on the webserver.

Answer (score 3):

In your PHP.INI file, try to comment all the extensions lines and restart IIS. Take note that MySql will no longer work. Do some tests.

If it's successfull, uncomment back the mySql line. Do some tests.

If it's unsucessfull, them I can't help you more. I suspect that's a loaded extension causing the error. You have to find which one...

Hope this helps.

vIceBerg

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using PHP 5.2.6 (latest version).  I'm also assuming your using ISAPI from the directions in your link.

There seem to be a lot of bug reports for PHP on IIS with access violations.

[Here](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43303) and [here](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44869) or a [list](http://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&status=&search_for=IIS+access+violation&php_os=&boolean=1&author_email=&bug_age=0&by=&order_by=&direction=&phpver=&limit=30&assign=&reorder_by=id)

So far the only suggestion I've found is to try FastCGI instead of ISAPI.

I've never had to mess with debugging PHP itself, my own scripts of cource, but not PHP.  There are instructions for [generating a backtrace](http://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace-win32.php) and some [general debugging info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/debugger.php).

Edit -- After reading viceBerg's answer I remembered another possible cause was non-thread safe PHP extensions and IIS not liking each other.  It might be worth it to disable them all and enable them one at a time but it's only really useful if you can get a script to cause that error consistently.

Without a consistent, reproducible error this will be very hard to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. I disabled all the extensions and started added one at a time and only the ones I needed to use (mysql,mbstring etc). I also had to copy php.ini into System32 folder (even though I had it in the system Path). Voila, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the libmysql.dll that came with php to windows\system32